# when using twitter api on ios , request token invalid

Tags: ios, twitter

I am using WBShareKit (a sharekit which supports Twitter, Weibo, and so on), when I change my appkey and appsecret to my own applications key, I get the following error message:

> "Whoa there!
>
> The request token for this page is invalid. It may have already been used, or expired because it is too old. Please go back to the site or application that sent you here and try again; it was probably just a mistake."

I do not know why it happens.  When I use the other applications appkey and appsecret, it works fine. But using mine, it doesn't work.